# How do I get product/parcelID from particular Assigned address using struct and mapping?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, mapping

```
struct Sellers{
    address sellerAddress;
    uint parcelId;
    uint parcelPrice;
}
```

In this struct I've entered multiple parcel Ids to sellerAddress and I've retreived them using _sellerAddress.

But Now I want to retreive SellerAddress from ParcelId?

What is the exact logic for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping from parcelId to Seller struct, like this:

```
struct Seller {
    address sellerAddress;
    uint parcelId;
    uint parcelPrice;
}

mapping(uint => Seller) sellers;
```

Then you can access the seller address from parcel id like this:

```
sellers[parcelId].sellerAddress;
```